# Dask worker post-processing

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I'm new to dask and am trying to implement some post-processing tasks when workers shutdown.
I'm currently using an EC2Cluster with n_workers=5

The cluster is created each time I need to run my large task. The task outputs a bunch of files which I want to send to AWS S3.

How would I implement a "post-processing" function that would run on each worker to send any logs and outputs to my AWS S3?

Thanks in advance

```
def complex():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('hard')
    print(get_worker().id)

    return 'hard'


class DaskWorkerHandler(WorkerPlugin):
    """
    Worker life-cycle handler
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_id = None

    def setup(self, worker):
        self.worker_id = worker.id

    def teardown(self, worker):
        print(f"tearing down - {self.worker_id}. thread={threading.get_ident()}")

        # some post processing on the worker server
        # eg. post files to S3 etc...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=5)
    print(f"cluster_name={cluster.name}")

    shutdown_handler = DaskWorkerHandler()
    client = Client(cluster)
    client.register_worker_plugin(shutdown_handler)

    future = client.submit(complex)
    result = future.result()
```

Comment: Could you please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (maybe using LocalCluster)? It'll allow us to help you better, because the solution here would depend a lot on your workflow, what Dask collections you're using, etc. :)

Comment: @pavithraes thanks for the reply. I've attached a simple code snippet.
I guess my question would be, does "teardown" run on the worker box such that I can copy local files and stuff to S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Python’s standard logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) to log whatever you'd like as the workers are running and then use the worker plugin you wrote to save these logs to an S3 bucket on teardown (check out the docs on [logging in Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/debug.html#logs) for more details). Here's an example:

```py
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, get_worker
from dask.distributed.diagnostics.plugin import WorkerPlugin
import fsspec
import logging

def complex():
    logger = logging.getLogger("distributed.worker")
    logger.error("Got here")
    return 'hard'


class DaskWorkerHandler(WorkerPlugin):
    """Worker life-cycle handler."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_id = None

    def setup(self, worker):
        self.worker_id = worker.id

    def teardown(self, worker):
        logs = worker.get_logs()
        # replace with S3 path
        with fsspec.open(f"worker-{self.worker_id}-logs.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join([str(log) for log in logs]))


cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=5)
client = Client(cluster)

shutdown_handler = DaskWorkerHandler()
client.register_worker_plugin(shutdown_handler)

future = client.submit(complex)
result = future.result()


client.close()
cluster.close()
```